# Multiple alignment with tcboxmath for multiline equation within itemize environment

Tags: align, tcolorbox, itemize, split

I'd like to have an `itemize` environment. Each item is followed by an equation. (may be longer than 1 line). Now each equation (both single line and multline) should be surrounded by a coloured box. And the equations should be aligned. (so `\sigma_{n \nu \mu}` should be below `\sigma_{n \nu}`) What I've tried so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,theorems}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item die Kraftwellen, die sich aus dem Quadrat $B_{\delta s}^{2}$ der $\nu$-ten Ständerwelle bilden
        \begin{equation}
        \tcbset{fonttitle=\scriptsize}
        \tcboxmath[colback=white,colframe=blue]{\sigma_{n \nu} = aaa}
        \label{eq: Statorschwingung}
        \end{equation}
    \item die Kraftwellen, die sich aus dem Produkt $2 \cdot B_{\delta s} \cdot B_{\delta r}$ der $\nu$-ten Ständerwelle mit der $\mu$-ten Läuferwelle bilden
        \begin{equation}
        \tcbset{fonttitle=\scriptsize}
        \begin{split}
        \tcboxmath[colback=white,colframe=gray]{\sigma_{n \nu \mu} &= bbb + ccc \\
            &= eee - ddd}
        \end{split}
        \end{equation}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Running this I get the following error:
`Missing } inserted.<inserted text>}\end{split}`

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want? I simply nested the `split` environment in the tcolorbox:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{listings,theorems}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item die Kraftwellen, die sich aus dem Quadrat $B_{\delta s}^{2}$ der $\nu$-ten Ständerwelle bilden
            \begin{equation}
            \tcbset{fonttitle=\scriptsize}
            \tcboxmath[colback=white,colframe=blue]{\sigma_{n \nu} = aaa}
            \label{eq: Statorschwingung}
            \end{equation}
        \item die Kraftwellen, die sich aus dem Produkt $2 \cdot B_{\delta s} \cdot B_{\delta r}$ der $\nu$-ten Ständerwelle mit der $\mu$-ten Läuferwelle bilden
            \begin{equation}
            \tcbset{fonttitle=\scriptsize}
            \tcboxmath[colback=white,colframe=gray]{\begin{split}
            \sigma_{n \nu \mu} &= bbb + ccc \\ & = eee - ddd
         \end{split}}
         \end{equation}
    \end{itemize}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\sigma_{n \nu}` should also be aligned to `\sigma_{n \nu \mu}`. But concerning the colorbox, yes, this is what I wanted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how to obtain it, since the equations are not in the same item.

Comment: But the other advice was already very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @Domi1908; you can align the sigmas adding before the last  split environment `{}\hskip 3.15em` (found by trial and error).